# String comparisons of case sensitive in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have to write a query that returns the number of students whose first
name is John in mysql but String comparisons should be case sensitive.

```
create TABLE students
(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
firstName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
lastName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
)
```

i tried

```
select count(*)
  from students 
 WHERE firstName COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = 'John'
```

but it only works on sql server 2008

i also tried

```
select count(*)
  from students 
 WHERE firstName COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS like 'John'
```

but it does not differ in 'JOHN' and 'John'

I have to get the answer right on website:https://www.testdome.com/d/sql-interview-questions/17
as this is my assignment.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! SO is not a cod writing service. We expect at least some effort from your side, therefore, please show us what you have tried so far, what you want to achieve and what issues you are facing. Cheers :)

Comment: i tried COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS='John' but it does not work in mysql only sql server

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
select count(*) from students WHERE BINARY firstName = 'john'
```

Try this updated code:

```
select count(*) from students WHERE HEX(firstName) = HEX('john')
```

Comment: it should work specifically in the compiler of link https://www.testdome.com/d/sql-interview-questions/17